# What would happen if $E=mc^2$ happened to every atom?

Tags: experimental-physics, mass-energy

If every atom turned into energy, if it is even possible, what would happen?

Comment: We would all be gone, and there would be no one to care what happens!

Comment: $E=mc^2$ is "happening to" every atom in the universe right now, in that atom's rest frame.  Are you asking what would happen if all atoms had the same rest frame?

Comment: @WillO Yeah... this isn't a stack exchange type of question. It's more of a 'what if' Quora type question. Moderators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the relativistic mass energy relationship is
$$
E = \sqrt{m^2c^4+p^2c^2}=mc^2 + \frac{1}{2}mv^2+\cdots
$$
making the transformation $E\rightarrow mc^2$ means that you are effectively setting all the kinetic energy that every particle has to $0$. In essence, you are removing all the heat from the universe. Furthermore, you are destroying every particle that is massless, so no more light.

There would be MANY repercussions to this. The CMB would disappear. Your pets would die. All cream would become ice cream. Also it would be the start of a light show...

Every star in the Universe would suddenly lose the pressure gradient that supports it against gravity. Stars would begin to collapse, converting gravitational energy to kinetic energy, reestablishing those pressure gradients. Unfortunately not every star will have the right range of masses in order to reach hydrostatic equilibrium again.

Billions of billions of stars will go supernova, their light spreading in all directions. If some humans survive this cataclysmic of cold, they would, after a decade or two, begin to see bright lights form in the sky, only to die away with the passage of time. These sparkles would be very few, but very bright at first. As years, and centuries, and millennia, and eons passed, there would be more of them but they would be much dimmer. This show of sparkles would last for a few billion years, until the light reaching Earth from distant supernova was redshifted out of visible range.

Radio astronomers a hundred billions years from now would continue to detect this sparkle show. They would find it is pretty isotropic and homogenous, since the distribution of stars at such large scales is too. Maybe they'd give it a name. Maybe they'd name it the CMB.

Answer (score 3):

> If every atom turned into energy

It already is.

Matter is energy.  That's what $E=mc^2$ means.

> if it is even possible

Happily it is happening all around you, all the time to some extent.  The universe would not exist without this.  All the processes that keep you alive, from the Sun generating energy to the chemistry in your body keeping you alive are relying on the ability to convert mass to energy and energy to mass.

> what would happen?

If you mean if all mass was instantly converted to massless energy ….

If a tree falls in the wood and no-one hears it, does it happen ?  We're pretty much into this territory as no mass means no humans and no humans means I, for one, won't be around to consider what happens.

If I was magically the only lump of mass left intact I wouldn't be for long because I'm suddenly surrounded by a dense field of energy (something like the heart of a thermonuclear weapon) and suddenly not surrounded by all the things I need to live (like oxygen, sunlight, pizza).

So there's no happy ending here.